# How to remove deleted scenes from build settings

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]After adding scenes to build settings then deleting them, the deleted scenes are still showing up. Problem is its affecting scene count. They all show up as a valid scene even though it says deleted. Highlighting them all and selecting remove selections does nothing.

```
EditorBuildSettingsScene[] scenes = EditorBuildSettings.scenes;
Debug.Log(scenes.Length);
```

This log statement returns ALL scenes even the deleted ones.

Answer (score 4):

You could filter out all `EditorBuildSettingsScene` which have a `File.Exists(scenePath) = false` like

```c#
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;

public static class EditorBuildSettingsTools
{
    [MenuItem("CustomBuildTools/RemoveDeletedScenes")]
    public static void CleanUpDeletedScenes()
    {
        var currentScenes = EditorBuildSettings.scenes;
        var filteredScenes = currentScenes.Where(ebss => File.Exists(ebss.path)).ToArray();
        EditorBuildSettings.scenes = filteredScenes;
    }
}
```

Place this into a folder named `Editor` so it is excluded from a build e.g. like

```
Assets/Editor/EditorBuildSettingsTools.cs
```

[image]

---

**Update:**

You ould further automatize this and in addition / instead of the manual menu item also clean up via some editor events. For instance e.g. as a callback to [`AssetModificationProcessor.OnWillSaveAssets`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetModificationProcessor.OnWillSaveAssets.html)

Comment: Ooh thank you, that worked. The "Editor" directory was not there, created a new one. Unity can be running while this is done, it dynamically red the new file and added the menu entry.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of *derhug*   can not seems working.  For example, when you delete a folder via script that contain scene  and call the method `CleanUpDeletedScenes` the file scene exist in same frame because it is in cache. I advice  of use the method `AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath` to check if exist scene file:

```c#
public static void CleanUpDeletedScenes() {
   currentScenes = EditorBuildSettings.scenes;
   var filteredScenes = currentScenes.Where(ebss => AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(ebss.path, typeof(SceneAsset)) != null).ToArray();
}
```